# Why antl4 base method (C#) has "int[] SerializedAtn" signature, but autogenerated code is "string SerializedAtn"?

Tags: c#, antlr4

Method in Generated `<GrammarName>Lexer` class:

```c#
public override string SerializedAtn { get { return new string(_serializedATN); } }
```

Method in base Recognizer class from which the Lexer is derived:

```c#
 public virtual int[] SerializedAtn
```

Same error is in the `<GrammarName>Parser`.

Please advise. I am not sure if the grammar itself has anything to do with it.

Comment: You should replace all antlr refs in .csproj with `<ItemGroup><PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.11.1" /><PackageReference Include="Antlr4BuildTasks" Version="12.2.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>` and `<ItemGroup><Antlr4 Include="MyGrammar.g4" />
</ItemGroup>` and let the Antlr4BuildTasks do the work for you. Do not download  `www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar`, do not run the Antlr4 tool manually, do not include the generated .cs files for parser and lexer, and do not install Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in v4 that changed from `string` to `int[]`. The compilation error you now get is because you're using a different ANTLR runtime version than the version you used to generate your parser classes. Always use the same versions. I recommend using the most recent:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.11.1" />
```

and use this to generate your parser classes: [www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar](https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar)

#### EDIT

Ah, I see kaby76 suggest not do download the JAR but to use a Antlr4BuildTasks for it (I'm sure that suggest is sound, I just don't have much experience in ANTLR development + C#). Whatever you decide to do, make sure that the underlying version of the ANTLR tool (whether that is the tool included in the JAR or the the tool from the Antlr4BuildTasks) is the same as the ANTLR runtime version. The fact that the versions do not match is (most likely) the issue you are facing now.